# SQL Error #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE wp_locations (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `city` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT `city_name` UNIQUE (`city`, `name`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I got an sql error '#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your combined key is too long. Make seperate keys or reduce column lengths

Comment: Create a new column `unique_id binary(16)`, concatenate two columns, hash them and save **RAW hash**  to `unique_id`, make `unique_id` unique. Job done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL always reserves the max amount for a `UTF8` field which is 4 bytes so with `255  + 255`  with your `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`;  you are over the 767 max key length limit.

You can only reduce the single varchar length or don't use a composite key.

Comment: This was the problem, I changed it to varchar 128 and it worked

Comment: 128 x 4 x 2  > 767  you should reduce  again (try and let me know)

Comment: but as I said, it works so there is no problem anymore

Comment: @PaulRoefs  ops .. Excuse me .. I got it wrong ... well .. I'm glad you've solved the problem

Answer (score 8):

I had the same exact issue. I've added these lines to a new conifg file in /etc/my.conf.d directory named umb4-support.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_large_prefix=true
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=true
```

After restarting the maria db service, my import scripts ran without this issue.
Godspeed!

Comment: This is the solution - gets the database engine to accept wider indexes.  The accepted answer gives the reason for the problem but is not a solution if you need the composite key.  These settings worked for me.
`innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=on
innodb_default_row_format=dynamic
innodb_large_prefix=1
innodb_file_format_max=Barracuda`