# Mysql import of laravel voyager database error - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, syntax-error, voyager

Cant seem to upload a laravel database to a live server because of the specified key is too long. [SQL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660396/sql-error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes) example shows that the key constraint is too long, however it is not just on one table it is on many. Is there a way to update this or change my DB to be able to upload it? I followed the guide in the app service provider but i am not sure if I have to drop the DB, then migrate again with the key  constraint on the boot() method on the app service provider. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the adding defaultStringLength to the boot method does work however because I was using vendor scripts, I could not rollback my migrations as the migrations were created by the BREAD Controller in Voyager. In order to get the MYSQL import to work, without losing data or rolling and changing the migrations I had to manually, with Sequel Pro or whatever you are using, and change manually each `varchar('255')` to `varchar('191')`.

This saved me from deleting and having to rollback.

Adding:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; // add this 

Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

to the AppServiceProvider.php will work from now on because any other migration I create with the BREAD controller will have the default `191` added to the string length.

For reference: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Answer (score 0):

add `defaultStringLength` to boot method of AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; // add this 

Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

rollback migrations and try again after adding this line. It will work.

Comment: just concerned at doing it, reuploading the data, and the same problem arising because of the saved sql state

Comment: I had done this before so I can tell you that it will work properly. Just rollback your migration files and try again. It's fresh laravel setup?

Comment: you can have a look at this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17508

Comment: no its not fresh its a project and i am using voyager package so makes it more tricky as they have their own migrations so currently getting errors on rollback.

Comment: Thanks though. I think it will work just need to tinker the setup